# Multi website - how to use media url in phtml file

Tags: multistore, magento2.3.4, multi-website

i have setup multi website in magento 2.3.4 on single Domain with setting - **Add Store Code to Urls**

[image]

my website URLs are like below now
**1: example.com/in
2: example.com/us**

i want to call images from media folder , earlier i use below code that is not working after multi store

**Earlier code :** getBaseUrl(); ?>media/abc.png

Issue : after muti store setup my image URL becomes like example.com/us/media/abc.png and this causes issue with images ,

Please help way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

try to get the base url based on the store, something like,

```
* @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $this->_storeManager
*/

$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

In database you should have a base url for each store ID correct? In **core_config_data** table, in column **path** search this **web/secure/base_url** and check if appears 2 results with different scopes.
Hope it helps :D